# Eto.Forms and SQLite - crossplatform development for Windows/OSX

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, cross-platform

I really like [Eto.Forms](https://github.com/picoe/Eto), I think they will be boost the crossplatform developments in the future.

But after creating my first UI-heavy application (both Windows and OSX) I realized that I need a database engine too.

My fav for that project is [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) but I cannot find a corresponding package on NuGet for that.

Has anyone experiences with it?